# ffmpeg image to video frame length

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg

hi i am useing ffmpeg to convert images into videos but images loads very fast and movie end very shortly how can i add a delay in images

i am useing this command

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i %03d.jpg  -vframes 100 abc.avi
```

Comment: `ffmpeg` is known as deprecated. Running this command shall note you and advice to use `avconv` instead. With the same arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower the -r value, you have it currently set to 10 frames per second.